# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0}\left({\frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{\sin(ax)-\sin(bx)}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to evaluate the following limit, where a and b are any constants, without using L'Hopital's rules.

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left({\frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{\sin(ax)-\sin(bx)}}\right)$$

Comment: Write out the Taylor series for each piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution. Convert the denominator to product using trigonometric formulas. Now divide both numerator and denominator by ax-bx. But we should use the fact that e ^ax/ ax ---> 1 where the latter follows from the Taylor series expansion for the function $f(x)=e ^{ax}.$ So $ L=\frac{a-b}{a-b} =1.$

Answer (score 1):

$e^{ax} - e^{bx} = (a - b)x + o(x^2)$, and $\sin(ax) - \sin(bx) = 2\sin(\frac{(a-b)x}{2})\cos(\frac{(a+b)x}{2})$. So:

$\dfrac{e^{ax} - e^{bx}}{\sin(ax) - \sin(bx)} = \dfrac{(a-b)x + o(x^2)}{(a-b)x + o(x^3)} = \dfrac{a - b + o(x)}{a - b + o(x^2)}$, from this the limit is seen to be $\dfrac{a-b}{a-b} = 1$

Answer (score 0):

There's really no reasonably easy way to do this problem without derivatives, so it's silly that L'hopital's rule is not allowed. Since derivatives are almost a requirement to do this problem without tremendous work, use Taylor expansion theorem with Taylor approximations going out to first order, and you'll get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using  [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) formula,

$${\frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{\sin(ax)-\sin(bx)}}=\frac{e^{bx}\left(e^{(a-b)x}-1\right)}{2\sin\left(\dfrac{ax-bx}2\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{ax+bx}2\right)}$$

Now use
$$\lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{e^h-1}h\right)=1\text{ and } \lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{\sin h}h\right)=1$$